# Button moving out of view - android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with 3 `Buttons` vertically aligned one below the other. In between each button, i have set a `LinearLayout` whose visibility is `GONE` initially. When the 1st button is clicked, the `LinearLayout` beneath it is changed to `VISIBLE` and the list view which i have defined in that layout comes in view while the remaining 2 `Buttons` remain attached to the `LinearLayout`.

The problem is that if the list view within the `LinearLayout`t (which i have added using java code) is too big, then the 2 `Buttons` below the 1st one go out of view. What remains is the layout beneath the 1st button.

I want the 2 `Buttons` to be bound to the view. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my layout:

```
      LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonContact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contacts" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_style" 
            android:textColor="#E6E6E6"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutContact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Call Logs" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_style" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"                
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonVm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Voicemail" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutVm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put your XML layout code So that it would be easy for everyone to understand your problem.

Comment: no no listview wont work inside scrollview

Comment: give height of linear layout as wrap content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your problem correct, you want the last buttons to be in the view irrespective of the list height. Then i would suggest you to use weight for the hidden LinearLayout, use `android:layout_weight=1` to achieve your requirement.

Comment: hey now i have another query. the last buttons are fixed at the bottom whenever the 1st button is pressed. if the list that i am displaying is very small as to not fully occupy the screen then those buttons should be attached below the linear layout and not at the very bottom of the screen. is there a way to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

```
android:scrollbars="true"
```

Try putting scrollbars

Comment: i dont want to put scrollbars because i want all the 3 buttons to be visible at the same time.